# Detached HEAD on same commit as main?

Tags: git, github, git-checkout, git-log

I'm not really sure how I got my repository in this situation, and it's not even a problem anymore, but I'd like to learn about what happened so I don't feel so lost next time.

When doing a pull, I was warned I was in detached HEAD state. `git status` showed the following ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wq2Ha.png)):

```
HEAD detached at 44422b7
```

So I ran `git log` to find out how far back from main I was, and it showed ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gHgC.png)):

```
commit 44422b74b6826291479ee7a17fe18bb4acca6355 (HEAD, main)
```

It didn't make much sense to me, as I seemed to be in the same commit as the main branch but, eager to solve the problem, I ran `git checkout main`, and then the next `git log` showed, instead ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgODc.png)),

```
commit 44422b74b6826291479ee7a17fe18bb4acca6355 (HEAD -> main)
```

and all started working as I initially expected.

So I'm left trying to understand the difference between what `git log` showed on the first and second time I ran it (the one with the arrow vs. the one with just a comma), and maybe understand how I got to that situation in the first place.

Thanks for any help I can get.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why did my Git repo enter a detached HEAD state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965676/why-did-my-git-repo-enter-a-detached-head-state)

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I think it answers half of it. More specifically, question number 2, going with the division made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72861360/9899424).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are really two separate questions:

1. > trying to understand the difference between what git log showed on the first and second time I ran it (the one with the arrow vs. the one with just a comma),
2. > understand how I got to that situation in the first place.

The answer to question 2 is in [Why did my Git repo enter a detached HEAD state?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3965676/1256452)

The answer to question 1 is simpler: the first one shows the detached-HEAD state and the second, with the arrow in it, shows the attached-HEAD state.  But we can expound on this a bit: in particular, the whole concept of "detached HEAD" in the first place is a bit peculiar.  Before we can describe it, though, we have to know what an *attached* HEAD is!  In one way it's obvious—it's the opposite of a *detached* HEAD—but that's just circular reasoning.  We need something more basic, and this lies in *how Git finds commits*.

First, remember that every Git commit has a unique hash ID:

> ```
> commit 44422b74b6826291479ee7a17fe18bb4acca6355
> ```

That big ugly string of letters-and-digits is a number, expressed in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal).  (In decimal it's 389687007142770230305517186390235637298437448533, which isn't really any better.  In fact, Git has to have it in hexadecimal, or in binary, because of the way it looks these up by prefix in its database, which in part uses [tries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) of various power-of-two sizes.)  This hash ID is used as a *key* in a simple [key-value database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key%E2%80%93value_database); the value is the internal Git representation of the commit.

So Git *needs* this commit hash ID to find this commit.  You must give Git the hash ID: that's the only way Git has, for looking up the commit.  But who wants to type in `44422b74b6826291479ee7a17fe18bb4acca6355` over and over again?  Would you even get it right?  What if you could just say `main` and Git could look up `main`—or, technically, `refs/heads/main`—in a secondary key-value store and *find* `44422b74b6826291479ee7a17fe18bb4acca6355`?  Wouldn't that be nicer?

Yes, it is in fact nicer, and that's what we do: we type in `main` or `v1.2` or `origin/develop`, and Git looks that up in this secondary database to get the raw hash ID.  From there, Git finds the commit we want.

When you're "on a branch", as `git status` says about it, what this means is that every *new* commit you make will *update the current branch name*.  So if you're `on branch main` and you make a *new* commit and its hash ID is `a123456...` or whatever, Git will store the *new* commit's hash ID, `a123456...` or whatever, under the *name* `main`.  (The old commit-hash-ID—`44422b74b6826291479ee7a17fe18bb4acca6355`—goes into the new commit, so that it's now the *second-to-last* commit.)

What all *this* means, in turn, is that Git needs to know, at all times, which *branch name* is the name it should update whenever you make a new commit.  To remember that branch name, Git "attaches" the special name `HEAD` *to* the branch name.

(The current implementation of this is that Git writes `ref: refs/heads/main` into `.git/HEAD`.  However, this implementation could change in the future.  The current implementation is already different from the previous one, and has already changed somewhat to handle added working trees, as now it's sometimes not `.git/HEAD` at all: that's just for the *main* working tree.)

#### So that's an attached HEAD, and therefore ...

An *attached HEAD* is when HEAD contains the name of a branch.  The branch name contained *in* HEAD is the current branch.  The branch name itself, in the database full of name-to-hash-ID mappings, contains the hash ID of the *current commit*.  So `HEAD` provides two pieces of information:

- the current branch name, and
- the current commit hash ID (indirectly).

To *detach* HEAD, Git simply writes the raw hash ID of some commit—*any* existing commit—into `HEAD`.  Now that `.git/HEAD` contains a raw hash ID, there is no current *branch name*, but there's still a *current commit hash ID*.  It's just that `HEAD` now holds it *directly*.  There's no need to look up the name in the names database.

Everything else you do still works the same as before: in particular, if you create a *new* commit, the new commit connects (backwards, as commits do) to the commit that *was* current when you made the new one; and now the new commit *is* the current commit, i.e., Git has stored its hash ID in `HEAD`.

If you *do* make such a commit and run `git log`, you'll see:

```
commit a123456... (HEAD)
[your new commit]

commit 44422b74b6826291479ee7a17fe18bb4acca6355 (main)
[your old commit]
```

since `git log` works by starting at the *current* commit and working backwards, one commit at a time.  But since you *didn't* make a new one, both the name `HEAD` *and* the name `main` mean "commit 44422b74b6826291479ee7a17fe18bb4acca6355", so you get:

```
commit 44422b74b6826291479ee7a17fe18bb4acca6355 (HEAD, main)
```

When `HEAD` is attached, Git prints it with that forward-arrow notation (since Git 2.10: prior to 2.10.0, Git printed `HEAD, main` for both cases).

Answer (score 2):

Branches are labels that point at a commit.

HEAD always points at the currently checked out commit.

```
commit 44422b74b6826291479ee7a17fe18bb4acca6355 (HEAD, main)

commit 44422b74b6826291479ee7a17fe18bb4acca6355 (HEAD -> main)
```

Both say you are at commit 44422b74b6826291479ee7a17fe18bb4acca6355.
Both say HEAD and main point at that commit.
But `HEAD -> main` says main is the currently checked out branch.

When you run `git commit` a new commit is made and the currently checked out branch, and HEAD, are moved to it.

It's possible to have *no* branch checked out, that is a detached HEAD state. In this case when you `git commit` only HEAD moves. No branch is tracking your commit. If you `git checkout` or `git switch` away, there will be (almost) nothing referring to those detached commits.

There's plenty of ways to get into a detached HEAD state, the most basic is to checkout a commit ID. `git checkout 4ba97c6ffc71f88a4de4ed88b188dbec2e5ff325`.

You can get out of a detached HEAD state by checking out a branch, like you did. Or you can make a new branch where you're at.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to use `git switch main`, not `git checkout main`.

By using [`git switch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309), you lower the risk to end up with a [detached HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309), because you would get the error message (when switching to a commit or a remote branch)

```
fatal: a branch is expected, got remote branch 'origin/master'
```

You would need to add explicitly the `--detach` option in order to end up with a detached HEAD.